# Avoid having my boss from getting the reply from a calendar invite

Tags: microsoft-outlook

If I am sending an calendar invite on my boss behalf, is there a way for me to get the response instead of him?

Comment: Ask your IT people if this is allowed or configured on your systems.

Answer (score 1):

Your boss can change the Delegate settings. Responses to this meeting invite only send to you(delegate only)

[image]

Found this from [this thread.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/61c3131c-5bab-4c76-ac9d-baa9f79cc02f/meeting-request-responses?forum=officeitproprevious)